# Amount value only displaying 3 digits on email template in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am fetching opportunity data from salesforce to marketing for sending emails. But amount value not populating correctly on email template only three digits populating.
For example: if amount value 89.90 means populating as 89.9

if amount value 5.98 means populating as 5.98

Please help me to add complete amount with all digit values in email template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to leverage [format() ampscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/Format.html)

`format(fieldname, "##.00")`

The 0 above ensures trailing zeros

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual force page to display the values, you can use this:

```
<apex:outputText value = "{0, number, ###,###,###,###.000}">
<apex:param value = "{!variable}"/>
<apex:outputText>\
```

The ### represents the format of displaying the numbers. You can modify it according to your need.